# Categorical Mixture Model in Pymc3

Tags: pymc3

I'm new to Pymc3 and I'm trying to create the Categorical Mixture Model shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Categorical_mixture_model .  I'm having difficulty hooking up the 'x' variable.  I think it's because I have to make the z variable Deterministic, but I'm getting an error message at the line where 'x' is assigned : "ValueError: We expected 3 inputs but got 2.".  It looks like the p function only accepts 2 inputs so I'm stuck.  I've tried a bunch of different things, but haven't been able to get this to work yet.

```
import numpy as np
from pymc3 import *
import theano.tensor as t

K = 3 #NUMBER OF TOPICS
V = 20 #NUMBER OF WORDS
N = 15 #NUMBER OF DOCUMENTS

#GENERAETE RANDOM CATEGORICAL MIXTURES
data = np.ones([N,V])

@theano.compile.ops.as_op(itypes=[t.lscalar, t.dscalar, t.dscalar],otypes=[t.dvector])
def p(z=z, phi=phi):
    return [phi[z[i,j]] for i in range(D) for j in range(W)]

model = Model()
with model:

    alpha = np.ones(V)
    beta = np.ones(K)

    theta = [Dirichlet('theta_%i' % i, alpha, shape=V) for i in range(K)]
    phi = Dirichlet('phi', beta, shape=K)

    z = [Categorical('z_%i' % i, p = phi, shape=V) for i in range(N)]
    x = [Categorical('x_%i_%i' % (i,j), p=p(z[i][j],phi), observed=data[i,j]) for i in range(N) for j in range(V)]
    #x = [Categorical('x_%i_%i' % (i,j), p=theta[z[i][j]], observed=data[i,j]) for i in range(N) for j in range(V)]

    print "Created model.  Now begin sampling"
    step = Slice()
    trace = sample(n, step)

    trace.get_values('phi')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, in your example above, z and phi have no value which would allow them to be used as default values. We also don't have values for D and W.

As for the number of arguments, the function you define has 2 but your theano decorator above it has 3.  I'd suggest

```
@theano.compile.ops.as_op(itypes=[t.lscalar, t.dvector],otypes=[t.dvector])
def p(z, phi):
    return [phi[z[i,j]] for i,j in zip(range(D),range(W))]
```